# Use puppet to deploy bareos/bacula to server and clients

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, bacula, bareos

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I would really love to use puppet to deploy bareos on my servers.
To do this I'm using [netmanagers/bareos](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/netmanagers/bareos).

I'm using this profile to install bareos to my clients:

```
class profile::backup::client {
## Install bareos client ##
    class   {
            'bareos':
                    manage_client   =>      'true',
    }
```

}

This profile is used to install bareos to my bareos-server:

```
class profile::backup::server {
## Install bareos server ##
class   {
    'bareos':
        manage_client   =>  'true',
        manage_storage  =>  'true',
        manage_director =>  'true',
        manage_console  =>  'true', 
}

bareos::storage::device {
            'device':
                media_type  =>  'File',
                archive_device  =>  '/var/bareos/backup',
}
```

}

Okay - now I can deploy bareos-clients to my clients and the server to my server - this already works (it's magic ;-) ).

What I want to do next: I would like to configure the system automatically. So the server should be configured to contact the client (to do so, the server needs to know the FQDN and the given password of the client. The client has to apply server-dir as permitted director.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use puppet to deploy bareos (bacula-fork) to my nodes](http://serverfault.com/questions/748211/use-puppet-to-deploy-bareos-bacula-fork-to-my-nodes)